# Gridview row validation on button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am doing validation for `gridview` on button click.

My requirement is in `gridview` I can add multiple rows at a time. Suppose if I add 2 rows, In any of 2 rows there should be atleast a column with value `PURCHASER` then it satisfies my requirement.

But if in both rows there is not `PURCHASER` then it should prompt alert.

So what I wrote is

```
for (i = 0; i < GrdPartyInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
            if (GrdPartyInfo.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != "PURCHASER") {
                alert('There should be atleast one purchaser');
                return false;
            }    
        }
```

But what happens is, if I add `PURCHASER` in second row it still prompts me error. WHY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just checking the first value, and if it is not a purchaser, you output the error, ignoring other values. Instead this should be:

```
var hasPurchaser = false;
for (i = 0; i < GrdPartyInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
    if (GrdPartyInfo.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == "PURCHASER") {
        hasPurchaser = true;
    }    
}

if (!hasPurchaser) {
    alert('There should be at least one purchaser');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: let me try and check this one.!

Comment: yes it is working fine..will accept after checking througly.